# Is there a way to freeze luajit(or some jit) generated code, and use it wihtout jit compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, lua, jit, luajit

Since a jit compiler in luajit or elsewhere requires quite a bit a memory(for an embedded system), i wonder:

Is there a way to run luajit(or other jit based VM) on a system with plenty of memory , than freeze the code and reuse the program without a jit ?

Comment: Part of the memory cost is the redundant code and the information necessary for aborting execution of compiled code when it's invalidated. You can't really avoid that, as the JIT compiled code is still specialized under some assumptions that may be violated at run time, regardless of whether it's compiled JIT or AOT. Plus, you need the full bytecode and the interpreter in any case, and while those are tiny by Desktop standards they're not peanuts for some embedded platforms.

Answer (score 2):

No, LuaJIT cannot do this, because there is not enough information in the compiled code to recreate it in a different process (while ensuring that it is still equivalent to the original bytecode.)

Comment: Why? if i understand correctly , what lua jit does(simplified) is take some code path, compile them(using runtime data) to machine code, and let the program run the machine code instead of the bytecode. Where's the problem in freezing those results ?